# SQL - extract random sample from joined tables

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, random

I've to fill an empty table (TAB_A) with random records (5%) from TAB_B, joined with other 3 tables (C1, C2, C3).

Now, if I run the following query everything works well:

```
INSERT INTO TAB_A (field1,field2)
    SELECT TAB_B.ID_TASS, TAB_B.ID_SEZ
    FROM (SELECT TAB_B.*, row_number() 
            OVER (ORDER BY dbms_random.VALUE) r 
            FROM TAB_B) 
    WHERE r < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TAB_B)*0.05
```

The problem is that I need also to fill in the TAB_A.field3 whose values are in TAB_C3.
So I rewrite my previous query:

```
INSERT INTO TAB_A (field1,field2,field3)
    SELECT B.ID_TASS, B.ID_SEZ, C3.Z_ID
    FROM (SELECT B.*, row_number() 
            OVER (ORDER BY dbms_random.VALUE) r 
            FROM TAB_B B
                JOIN TAB_C1 C1 on C1.X_ID = B.X_ID
                JOIN TAB_C2 C2 on C2.Y_ID = C1.Y_ID
                JOIN TAB_C3 C3 on C3.Z_ID = C2.Z_ID
            WHERE C3.Z_ID = 9) 
    WHERE r < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B)*0.05
```

but an error occurs: ORA-00904: "C3.Z_ID" invalid identifier.

I think the problem could be in the statement "**SELECT B.ID_TASS, B.ID_SEZ, C3.Z_ID**", that I changed in "**SELECT TAB_B.ID_TASS, TAB_B.ID_SEZ, TAB_C3.Z_ID**".... but without success: the same error occurs again.

By the way, the following query works perfectely:

```
select count(*)
    from TAB_B B
        JOIN TAB_C1 C1 on C1.X_ID = B.X_ID
        JOIN TAB_C2 C2 on C2.Y_ID = C1.Y_ID
        JOIN TAB_C3 C3 on C3.Z_ID = C2.Z_ID
    WHERE C3.Z_ID = 9
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: If you're worried about performance you may want to look into using SAMPLE: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2065953

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

...

SELECT B.ID_TASS, B.ID_SEZ, **C3_Z_ID**

FROM (SELECT B.*, **C3.Z_ID AS C3_Z_ID,** row_number() 
...

Comment: tried, but no success: same error but on different field ORA-00904: "B.ID_SEZ" invalid identifier. So I rewrote: SELECT TASS_ID, SEZ_ID, C3_Z_ID
FROM (SELECT B.ID_TASS as TASS_ID, B.SEZIONE_NUM as SEZ_ID, C3.Z_ID AS C3_Z_ID, row_number() ... but a new error occurs: ORA-00942 Table or View not exists.

Comment: @albus2011: then try to change also WHERE r < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B)*0.05  to WHERE r < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM **TAB_B**)*0.05

Comment: done, but now the error is ORA-00001 Unique constraint violated.

Comment: @albus2011: has tab_a a primary key or unique constraints? try SELECT **DISTINCT** TASS_ID, SEZ_ID, C3_Z_ID

Comment: '@shurik - yes TAB_A has a primary key. I tried SELECT DISTINCT but ORA-00001 error again.

Comment: '@shurik: you'are right! TAB_A was not empty. After a DELETE it works! But without using DISTINCT. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The following should work although I havent tested

> 

```
INSERT INTO TAB_A (field1,field2,field3)
>     SELECT intTab.ID_TASS, intTab.ID_SEZ, intTab.Z_ID
>     FROM (SELECT B.*, c3.z_id,row_number() 
>             OVER (ORDER BY dbms_random.VALUE) r 
>             FROM TAB_B B
>                 JOIN TAB_C1 C1 on C1.X_ID = B.X_ID
>                 JOIN TAB_C2 C2 on C2.Y_ID = C1.Y_ID
>                 JOIN TAB_C3 C3 on C3.Z_ID = C2.Z_ID
>             WHERE C3.Z_ID = 9) intTab
>     WHERE intTab.r < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B)*0.05
```

Comment: '@josephj1989 - error ORA-00904: "intTab.Z_ID" invalid identifier